# no me funciona el método onTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy intentando hacer un videojuego, donde el personaje tiene que recoger 6 ítems para pasar al siguiente nivel. Uno de los ítems está encerrado en una cueva, para entrar necesita una llave que es la que abrirá la roca que bloquea la entrada de la cueva. He hecho dos scripts, uno del movimiento del personaje y otro para el movimiento de la roca.

Este es el código donde llamo al script que hace que la roca se mueva cuando el personaje coja el ítem con el tag "llave". El problema es que la roca se mueve antes de que se coja la llave. Se mueve desde el primer momento que pulso play, sin que haya cogido nada todavía.

````
```
    private AnimacionCueva animCueva;

    void Update()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

        
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, fuerzaSalto,0), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "llave") 
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            animCueva.moverPiedra()
                

        }
    }```
````

este es el script para que la roca se mueva.

````
```
    public Transform target;
    public float velocidad=3f;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moverPiedra();
    }
    public void moverPiedra()
    {
        float mover = velocidad * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, mover);
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

En tu script AnimacionCueva estas llamando a la funcion moverPiedra(), recuerda que dentro de tu funcion Update, todo lo que tengas dentro se ejecuta cada frame.
Por lo tanto tu roca se mueve desde que presionas el boton Play.

Elimina la llamada de tu funcion moverPiedra() de la funcion Update.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).